# Android Development: Combining two Java files

Tags: java, android, dialog, spinner

I have two different java files and was wondering if there was a way to combine them so that both codes were in one file.

The below simply creates a dialog box that does nothing when no is clicked and moves to a new activity if yes is clicked:

```
package com.example.top_tech_deals;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class AlertDialogActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.post);


    Button btnAlertTwoBtns = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAlertWithTwoBtns);






    /**
     * Showing Alert Dialog with Two Buttons one Positive Button with Label
     * "YES" one Negative Button with Label "NO"
     */
    btnAlertTwoBtns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Creating alert Dialog with two Buttons

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");

            // Setting Icon to Dialog
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

            // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                            // Write your code  here to execute after dialog

                            Intent k = new  Intent(AlertDialogActivity.this, Camera.class);
                             startActivity(k);

                            Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            // Setting Negative "NO" Button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog,    int which) {
                            // Write your code  here to execute after dialog
                            Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    });

}
}
```

This second code creates a drop down menu full of items the user can select:

```
package com.example.top_tech_deals;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class AndroidSpinnerExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spinex);

    // Spinner element
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // Spinner click listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    categories.add("Automobile");
    categories.add("Business Services");
    categories.add("Computers");
    categories.add("Education");
    categories.add("Personal");
    categories.add("Travel");

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Essentially what I want is one of my xml files to use both a dialog box and a drop down menu, however because I was having trouble putting both these codes into one java file I resorted to creating two different xml files, post.xml which is linked to AlertDialogActivity and spinex.xml which is linked to AndroidSpinnerExampleActivity. I tried linking the two java files to the same xml but I found that only one of the java files seemed to do anything, so I believe the only solution would be combining the two codes into one java file, but I always seem to get errors when I try this.

Comment: What is your objective to combine the Java files ?

Comment: Just in case I was unclear, the first code creates a dialogue box and the second creates a spinner (drop down list), both of which are in two different java files. At the moment I have two different xml files, but I want to combine these two java codes into one so that I can have one xml file with the dialogue box and a spinner.

Comment: You can do it but for that you have to remove public modified from one of the Java class which you have created and one will be the public class which will be the Java file name

Comment: I have tried removing the public section of one of the codes and then pasting it into the other java file but it seems like no matter what I do I always get errors..

Comment: Finally got it to work! Nore sure how... but this time when I pasted one of the java codes into the other I didn't get any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each public class must be in a separate file, with filename the same as the class. But if you change one of your classes to be not public, then OK. I think best practice is to keep your files as they are. It's way better for future maintainability to have your classes in separate files, so that you can easily find your classes.

Comment: The trouble is, I need one xml layout file to access both these java files and I can't seem to do that unless I combine the two codes.

Comment: I think you need to think carefully about the structure of your app. You cant have 2 Activities active at once. You need an xml for each Activity. Consider using fragments. Or merge your 2 activities into 1 activity if you can

Comment: Merging them is exactly the problem I'm having, no matter what I seem to do I always get errors I can't fix

Comment: Your dialog probably shouldnt extend Activity

Answer (score 1):

> Essentially what I want is one of my xml files to use both a dialog
>   box and a drop down menu, however because I was having trouble putting
>   both these codes into one java file I resorted to creating two
>   different xml files, post.xml which is linked to AlertDialogActivity
>   and spinex.xml which is linked to AndroidSpinnerExampleActivity.

Follow this steps:

- Create a layout file which contains a `Button` and a `Spinner`.
- Create a class that extends `Activity` and implements the `OnItemSelectedListener` interface
- Set the previously created layout as the content view for the activity above
- in the `onCreate` method you'll have:

  ```
  setContentView(R.layout.combinedlayout); 
  // must be in the combinedlayout
  Button btnAlertTwoBtns = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAlertWithTwoBtns);
  btnAlertTwoBtns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     // the rest of the listener code from your first class.
  }
  // must be in the combinedlayout
  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

  // Spinner click listener
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

  // Spinner Drop down elements
  List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
  categories.add("Automobile");
  categories.add("Business Services");
  categories.add("Computers");
  categories.add("Education");
  categories.add("Personal");
  categories.add("Travel");

  // Creating adapter for spinner
  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

  // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
  dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

  // attaching data adapter to spinner
  spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit confused by your question. Do you want to combine these activities so that you have ONE activity, with both the button that opens the dialog box and the spinner on the screen at the same time? If so, you should be able to do that.

Just make one xml file that contains both the button and the spinner:

```
<Button
    .... />

<Spinner
    .... />
```

Then, you can just have one Activity that will reference the spinner and the button, populating the spinner and assigning an onItemSelectedListener to the spinner. You can handle the button exactly as before.

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class AndroidSpinnerAndButtonExampleActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        // Spinner element
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        categories.add("Automobile");
        categories.add("Business Services");
        categories.add("Computers");
        categories.add("Education");
        categories.add("Personal");
        categories.add("Travel");

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        setSpinnerOnItemSelectedListener(spinner);

        Button btnAlertTwoBtns = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAlertWithTwoBtns);

        /**
         * Showing Alert Dialog with Two Buttons one Positive Button with Label
         * "YES" one Negative Button with Label "NO"
         */
        btnAlertTwoBtns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Creating alert Dialog with two Buttons

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                // Setting Dialog Title
                alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");

                // Setting Dialog Message
                alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");

                // Setting Icon to Dialog
                alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

                // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    // Write your code  here to execute after dialog

                    Intent k = new  Intent(this, Camera.class);
                    startActivity(k);

                    Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    });
                // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog,    int which) {
                        // Write your code  here to execute after dialog
                        Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.cancel();
                        }
                        });

                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();

                }
        });
    }

    public void setSpinnerOnItemSelectedListener(Spinner spinner){
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // On selecting a spinner item
                String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                // Showing selected spinner item
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: I seem to be getting errors with setSpinnerOnClickListener, AlertDialogActivity.this and Spinner.onItemSelectedListener

Comment: @JimmyK Those were all typos/mistakes from copy-paste. I have fixed them all. setSpinnerOnClickListener should actually be setSpinnerOnItemSelectedListener (I was referring to the method I defined at the bottom). AlertDialogActivity.this was incorrect, that was left over from copy pasting your code. Instead, you should just use 'this.' Instead of Spinner.onItemSelectedListener, you need to import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener and use that instead. I was just taking a guess at what it is called. I didn't actually compile this example.